# change the graphical icon for popup menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the graphical icon for popup menu > to ^ .When popup submenu is visible It need to change  as^ and when it is not visible it need to be in >.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
             $('.popup1').click(function(){
        $('.popupMenu1').slideToggle();
          })
    $('.popup2').click(function(){
        $('.popupMenu2').slideToggle();
          })
    $('.popup3').click(function(){
        $('.popupMenu3').slideToggle();
          })
    });
```

```css
.popupMenu1,.popupMenu2,.popupMenu3{
display:none; 
}
.popup1,.popup,.popup2,.popup3{
 cursor:pointer;
 
}
.popupMenu1 > li >a,.popup,.popupMenu2 > li >a,.popupMenu3 > li >a{
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="parentMobileMenu">
      <p class="popup1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow1"></span>Services</p>
       <ul class="popupMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">Product Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Enterprise Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Independent Testing Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Digital Transformation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Infrastructure &amp; Application Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle Applications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Big Data Analytic</a></li>
    </ul>
      <p class="popup2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow2"></span>Solutions</p>
        <ul  class="popupMenu2">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Auras</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Tapshop</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Temenos  AFIS</a>
                                <br> 
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                 <a href="#">MPoS</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Techcello</a>
                                <br>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
      <p class="popup3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow3"></span>Industries</p>
         <ul class="popupMenu3">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Independent Software Vendors</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Healthcare</a>
                                <br>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Retail</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Education</a>
                                <br>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Media and Publishing</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Insurance and Financial Services</a>
                                <br>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
      <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Digital</p>
      <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Perspectives</p>
      <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>About</p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add class in `CSS` and add `transform` property with `rotate-90deg` and whenever click happens you can `toggle` that `class` on `glyphicon`. Below I've added extra `rotate` class and toggling that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup1').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
    $('.popupMenu1').slideToggle();
  })
  $('.popup2').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
    $('.popupMenu2').slideToggle();
  })
  $('.popup3').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
    $('.popupMenu3').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.popupMenu1,
.popupMenu2,
.popupMenu3 {
  display: none;
}
.popup1,
.popup,
.popup2,
.popup3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popupMenu1 > li >a,
.popup,
.popupMenu2 > li >a,
.popupMenu3 > li >a {} 

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="parentMobileMenu">
  <p class="popup1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow1"></span>Services</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Product Engineering</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Enterprise Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Independent Testing Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Digital Transformation</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Infrastructure &amp; Application Support</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Oracle Applications</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Big Data Analytic</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="popup2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow2"></span>Solutions</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu2">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Auras</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Tapshop</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Temenos  AFIS</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">MPoS</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Techcello</a>
      <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="popup3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow3"></span>Industries</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu3">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Independent Software Vendors</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Healthcare</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Retail</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Education</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Media and Publishing</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Insurance and Financial Services</a>
      <br>
    </li>


  </ul>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Digital</p>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Perspectives</p>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>About</p>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your code can be more **simpler** with some common `class` and attaching click to one particular common `class`. Take below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.popup').click(function() {
     var target = $(this).data('target'); //get the target element
     $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
     $(target).slideToggle();
   })
});
```

```css
.popupMenu1,
.popupMenu2,
.popupMenu3 {
  display: none;
}
.popup1,
.popup,
.popup2,
.popup3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popupMenu1 > li >a,
.popup,
.popupMenu2 > li >a,
.popupMenu3 > li >a {} 

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  
  transition:all .5s; /*Animation*/
  /*Add for other browser specific as above you see in transform
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="parentMobileMenu">
  <p class="popup1 popup" data-target=".popupMenu1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow1"></span>Services</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Product Engineering</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Enterprise Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Independent Testing Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Digital Transformation</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Infrastructure &amp; Application Support</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Oracle Applications</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Big Data Analytic</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="popup2 popup" data-target=".popupMenu2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow2"></span>Solutions</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu2">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Auras</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Tapshop</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Temenos  AFIS</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">MPoS</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Techcello</a>
      <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="popup3 popup" data-target=".popupMenu3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow3"></span>Industries</p>
  <ul class="popupMenu3">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Independent Software Vendors</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Healthcare</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Retail</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Education</a>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Media and Publishing</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#">Insurance and Financial Services</a>
      <br>
    </li>


  </ul>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Digital</p>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Perspectives</p>
  <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>About</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a browser friendly solution. In cross browsers you will face many problems with this one.

Comment: @DemeterDimitri Its supports cross browsers, but browser version might depend.. But too old browsers might not support.. And this is one of the easiest trick to do..

Answer (score 1):

Just change your script like below

```
$('.popup1').click(function(){
    $('.popupMenu1').slideToggle();
    if $('.popup1').has_class('glyphicon-triangle-right') {
       $('.popup1').remove_class('glyphicon-triangle-right').add_class('glyphicon-triangle-top');
    } else {
       $('.popup1').remove_class('glyphicon-triangle-top').add_class('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jquery solution with a common function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                 $('.popup1').click(function(){
                     
            $('.popupMenu1').slideToggle();
                   toggleclass($(this));
              })
        $('.popup2').click(function(){
            $('.popupMenu2').slideToggle();
                   toggleclass($(this));
              })
        $('.popup3').click(function(){
            $('.popupMenu3').slideToggle();
                   toggleclass($(this));
              })
        });  

function toggleclass(obj){
  if ($(obj).find('span').hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-right')) {
    $(obj).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    $(obj).find('span').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
} else {
    $(obj).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
    $(obj).find('span').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
}
}
```

```css
 .popupMenu1,.popupMenu2,.popupMenu3{
    display:none; 
    }
    .popup1,.popup,.popup2,.popup3{
     cursor:pointer;
     
    }
    .popupMenu1 > li >a,.popup,.popupMenu2 > li >a,.popupMenu3 > li >a{
     
     
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="parentMobileMenu">
          <p class="popup1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow1"></span>Services</p>
           <ul class="popupMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Product Engineering</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Enterprise Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Independent Testing Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Digital Transformation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Infrastructure &amp; Application Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Oracle Applications</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Big Data Analytic</a></li>
        </ul>
          <p class="popup2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow2"></span>Solutions</p>
            <ul  class="popupMenu2">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Auras</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Tapshop</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Temenos  AFIS</a>
                                    <br> 
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                     <a href="#">MPoS</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Techcello</a>
                                    <br>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
          <p class="popup3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="arrow3"></span>Industries</p>
             <ul class="popupMenu3">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Independent Software Vendors</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Healthcare</a>
                                    <br>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Retail</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Education</a>
                                    <br>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Media and Publishing</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Insurance and Financial Services</a>
                                    <br>
                                </li>


                            </ul>
          <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Digital</p>
          <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>Perspectives</p>
          <p class="popup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>About</p>
       </div>
```